# How to append table with match of other table multiple column data

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have two table. one with 50 records in table A and other with 100 in table B.
Both table have customer id and date on it.
Both table have duplication but there are less number of unique customer in table with 50.

Now i wish to put date of customer in table B in front of customer in table A. a customer can appear more than 2 time in table B.

So number of time it appear, number of column appended with date in front of the customer.

`Id    Date
1   1/01/2016
2   2/01/2016
2   3/01/2016
3   1/01/2016
4   4/01/2016
5   5/01/2016
6   1/01/2016
7   3/01/2016
8   4/01/2016
9   1/01/2016
1   6/01/2016
10  1/01/2016`

For eg. this is table A

and Table B is

`Id     Date
1   1/01/2016
2   2/01/2016
2   3/01/2016
3   1/01/2016
4   4/01/2016
5   5/01/2016
6   1/01/2016
7   3/01/2016
8   4/01/2016
9   1/01/2016
1   6/01/2016
10  1/01/2016
1   15/01/2016
2   16/01/2016
2   17/01/2016
3   18/01/2016
4   19/01/2016
5   20/01/2016
6   21/01/2016
7   16/01/2016
8   20/01/2016
9   21/01/2016
1   16/01/2016
10  18/01/2016
1   19/01/2016
2   2/02/2016
2   30/01/2016
3   16/01/2016
4   31/01/2016
5   21/01/2016
6   18/01/2016
7   19/01/2016
8   16/01/2016
9   2/02/2016
1   18/01/2016
10  19/01/2016`

I wish to have output given under

> `Id   Date    Date1   Date2
>   1   1/01/2016   15/01/2016  19/01/2016
>   2   2/01/2016   16/01/2016  2/02/2016
>   2   3/01/2016   17/01/2016  30/01/2016
>   3   1/01/2016   18/01/2016  16/01/2016
>   4   4/01/2016   19/01/2016  31/01/2016
>   5   5/01/2016   20/01/2016  21/01/2016
>   6   1/01/2016   21/01/2016  18/01/2016
>   7   3/01/2016   16/01/2016  19/01/2016
>   8   4/01/2016   20/01/2016  16/01/2016
>   9   1/01/2016   21/01/2016  2/02/2016
>   1   6/01/2016   16/01/2016  18/01/2016
>   10  1/01/2016   18/01/2016  19/01/2016`

Any help is much much appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should explain how to use joins. Once you learn about that you can write SQL yourself.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

try understanding LEFT and Inner Joins

Comment: This is just an example i have provided. actual data base having 40k for A and 600k for B table. On table B, i have done partitioning. Client appeared in A will be appended with date in B based on rank. Ex. if rank 1, date will drop in column 1, rank 2 - date will drop in column 2 and so on. Inner join is the one that i use because i am interested in only those who appared in both end.

Comment: You can use multiple inner joins depending on filters you are afte within one parent query. If there is performance issue you should consider indexing your tables.

Answer (score 0):

try this (not easy)

```
with tmp1 as (
select row_number() over(order by (select null) ) - 1 newid , (row_number() over(order by (select null)) - 1) %12 rg1 ,  f1.*
from table2 f1
),
tableranked as (
select DENSE_RANK() over(partition by rg1 order by newid) rg2, f2.* 
from tmp1 f2
)
select  f1.id, f1.date, f4.date1, f4.date2 
from tableranked f1 inner join (select f2.id, f2.date as date1, f3.date as date2 , f2.rg1
                                from tableranked f2 
                                inner join tableranked f3 on f2.id=f3.id and f2.rg2+1=f3.rg2 and f2.rg1=f3.rg1
                                where f2.newid>=12 and f3.newid>=12
                                ) f4 on f1.id=f4.id and f1.rg1=f4.rg1
where f1.newid<12
```